# I need help understanding event handlers and functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I wrote HTML document and linked to my JS document.

when I execute the HTML file on my browser it only shows the "Click me!" button, but what I expected it to do was to show the result of my math function when clicked. But .. nothing happens. I'm very new to JavaScript so I'm sure this is a simple answer, but Googling isn't helping ... I appreciate any insight to what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the code from HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="JS/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="Math">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
        </p>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here's the JS file:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {return a * b;}

document.getElementById("Math") .innerHTML = myFunction(13, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you trying to do, but if you want to change the content of the "Math" element, you must call the function with parameters (eg: `onclick="myFunction(1,3)"`) and that function should replace the content:

```js
function myFunction(a, b) {
  document.getElementById("Math").innerHTML = a * b;
}
```

```html
<p id="Math">
<button onclick="myFunction(3,4)">Click me!</button>
</p>
```

Also if you want to preserve the button after clicking, this should be located outside the "Math" element to avoid being removed when replacing `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

One error in your html appears to be caused by an extra `"` in your lang attribute for your opening `html` tag. Try deleting it.

```html
<html lang="en">
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re including you script file in the header, so it runs before the dom is available.  When it executes, it won’t be able to find your id, so nothing will happen. You likely will see an error in the console that your document.getElementById call is returning undefined. Either include it at the end of the body, or add a defer tag:

```
<script src="JS/main.js" defer></script>
```

Also, as soon as the code runs, it overwrites the content of the p tag, including the button. Make the p and the button siblings.

Comment: Odd, I was instructed to specifically put that script tag into the header when being taught this stuff. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: It is common practice to put the scripts in the head, which I agree with. But you’ll need the defer tag to let the browser know not to run the JavaScript until after the dom has loaded. Otherwise document.getElementById("Math") will return as null, because that element doesn’t exist yet